# Vue.js - Inconsistencies between model and rendered content

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following minimum example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
    <ol>
        <li v-for="series in currentSeries" v-bind:data-id="series.id">
        The ID is <% series.id %>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="removeSeries">X</a>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </body>

  <script>
    vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    delimiters: ["<%", "%>"],
    data: {
        currentSeries: [{id: "1"}, {id: "2"}, {id: "3"}]
    },

    methods: {
        removeSeries: function(id) {
        this.currentSeries = this.currentSeries.filter(function(element) {
            return element.id != id;
        });
        }
    }
    });

   $(function() {
       $(document).on("click", ".removeSeries", function() {
       var id = $(this).parent().data("id");
       console.log(id);
       vm.removeSeries(id);
       });
   });
  </script>
</html>
```

I have a list of series in the variable currentSeries. I create a list of these, with adding an -tag to each item to remove it from the list.

If I click on the first 'X', the first element is removed from the list and ID 1 is shown in the console. Then, if I again click on the first element, it should remove the second element (which is now the first one). HOwever, the output id is still 1, i.e. the data-id was not updated of the node during the rendering.
What's the problem here and how to improve on this?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `jQuery` with Vue and both are conceptually different. Here jQuery is entirely unnecessary because you can use Vues built in click event:

```
// This will call remove series on click and remove the element by the given id
<a href="#" @click="removeSeries(series.id)">X</a>
```

Now, this will call your `removeSeries` for the given `id` and you can update the underlying model data however you want.

Here's the JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/vyra5nzc/

Just a note on delimiters, Vue also accepts `@{{data}}` as a delimiter  if you are using the double mustache in some other templating engine such as laravels blade.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround! I know, I mixed jQuery and Vue which might not be optimal. However, is there a clear reason why it does not work as I did in my original post? It would be good to understand, such that the same mistake is not done again (once it might be necessary to jointly use both techniques).

Comment: It's difficult to why that doesn't work, interestingly it works is you just use an `id` and then get it with `attr` but there is something happening when using `data` in `jQuery` so I guess the issue is to do with how jQuery implements that function. Here's the fiddle for `attr` and `id`: https://jsfiddle.net/5dpy5gfL/